# How to convert IMAP to POP3

Tags: email, imap, bash-scripting, pop3, network-protocols

I have an email server that only have IMAP interface. On the other side, I have another **Special-purpose** mail client (a kind of embedded system) that only accepts POP3 protocol.

[image]

How can I connect the client to the server? I should obviously run something on my own machine (with valid IP) to act as a relay/middleware/converter. Is it possible to do it using a bash/python script or make a standard linux tool to get the job done?

P.S. I cannot access neither the client nor the server to install/program anything.

P.S. The script may be active or passive, i.e. it may check IMAP when it receives a POP3 request, or may pro-actively fetch IMAP emails itself.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a unix/Linux tool just for that. It's called [fetchmail](http://www.fetchmail.info) and is some sort of commandline mail client.

You could easily configure it on a middleman server to fetch your imap mailbox, sync it to the local mailserver and configure that mailserver as pop3 on your remote pop3 only client.

Answer (score -1):

You can not directly convert your IMAP account into a POP3 account, you have to perform the following task to convert it.

1. **Add your POP3 Account** It can be done via the Account Settings Dialog Box.
2. **Transfer Your Mail Folder** After adding your account to POP3, all the emails that were in your IMAP inbox get downloaded. To transfer data simply select the emails or folder and simply perform the Copy or move command.
3. **Import and Export your Message Rules** It is recommended to export your Rules before you remove your IMAP account.
4. **Remove Your current IMAP account** After your data has been copied to your POP3 account, you can safely remove your IMAP account VIA The Account Setting Dialog box.